# sfdx sgd-git-delta plugin not recognized in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: deployment, sfdx-plugin, jenkins, cicd, sfdx-error

I have installed [sfdx git delta](https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta) plugin on my system. It works perfectly well when I execute locally on Git Bash / CMD / Visual Studio Code. But when I trigger the Jenkins pipeline, I see that sfdx does not find the installed plugin. Whereas, when I execute `sfdx plugins` locally I do get output of the plugins installed. What could be the reason for this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bug but I found out work around to this issue.

Even though plugin is installed on the system, when executed through Jenkins pipeline sfdx is unable to find the plugin. So, as a work around I added plugin install step in Jenkins pipeline

```
stage('Install sgd-git-delta plugin') {
            steps {
                script {
                    bat 'echo y | sfdx plugins:install sfdx-git-delta'
                }
            }
        }
```

At first run it installed the plugin and for subsequent execution it did not required this stage to execute.